# ListActivity not showing on screen, can only see a blank white screen

Tags: android, android-listview

I must be doing something stupid and missing some critical piece. Please help me debug this simple looking code for rendering ListActivity from a database

```
public class ExAct1 extends ListActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //I'm trying to use default view but using my own <ListView> also doesn't work
    //setContentView(R.layout.exp_list_act1); 

    From query = new Select().from(CategoryTable.class); //ActiveAndroid Library
    Cursor cursor = Cache.openDatabase().rawQuery(query.toSql(), query.getArguments());
    //startManagingCursor(cursor); //commenting or uncommenting has no effect

    this.setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            cursor,
            new String[] {"_id"}, //tried other column name from my table - no effect
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1},
            0));

    //these work - just to test Cursor is valid and has data
    Log.e(TAG, "Cursor Row Count: " + cursor.getCount()); // 3 rows
    Log.e(TAG, "Cursor Col Count: " + cursor.getColumnCount()); // 3 cols
  }
}
```

Honestly this is my entire class code. I can see the activity on the screen, the name in the header bar is same as defined in Manifest for that activity - but below the header I just see blank white screen.

Comment: ListView lv = getListView(); - Try adding this code after you have set the listadapter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to un-comment the line

//setContentView(R.layout.exp_list_act1);

And your xml layout file must contain a listview with id "@android:id/list"

Comment: It should still be showing something using the default layout (without calling setContentView)

Comment: I've done that - it doesn't work - the xml has listview with id @android:id/list. Also the documentation indicated without setContentView call the implementation will provide an android:id/list. Tried both - still only blank white screen

Comment: Are you sure the list is not being displayed? Maybe the textcolor is the same of the background color... It happened to me sometimes, creating confusion. Have you tried set a different background color?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAndroid uses "Id" as the default id column name. It can be changed to "_id", but if you don't remember doing so then this is probably your problem.

If so try this instead:

```
setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        cursor,
        new String[] {"Id"},
        new int[] {android.R.id.text1},
        0));
```

Alternatively, you can change the id column name in your CategoryTable class like so:

```
@Table(name = "category", id = BaseColumns._ID)
public class CategoryTable extends Model {...}
```

Comment: actually my @Table has the id = BaseColumns._ID - also I tried different columns to display - for example I've a col "category_name". Still doesn't work - I extensively tested the Cursor like looping the rows and columns and printing every value - all that works. Android system is not rendering the listView and i'm having a hell of time debuggin it.

Comment: can I ask a favor - can you copy paste the exact activity and run it on your device/emulator and see if it runs. You will need the <application android:name="com.activeandroid.app.Application" ...
and ofcourse your own sample table etc.
I need to know if the issue is only with my emulator :)

Comment: I just tried it (direct copy and paste of your code) and it's working fine for me on my Nexus 5. I can see the list with 1, 2, 3 as the items.